# Is there a way to not execute the worker on first app launch

Tags: android, android-workmanager

**Background:**
I am using WorkManager for updating the local cache every 2 days. This is configured in the Application class, so that it gets scheduled immediately on app launch.

**Problem:**
The worker gets executed immediately on first app launch instead of scheduling it.

**Code:**

```
        val configuration = Configuration.Builder()
                .setWorkerFactory(workerFactory)
                .setMinimumLoggingLevel(Log.DEBUG)
                .build()
        WorkManager.initialize(appContext, configuration)
        val workRequest = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<ConfigWorker>(2, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                .build()

        val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(appContext)
        workManager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
                "config_worker_request",
                ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP,
                workRequest
        )
```

I was actually looking for something which doesn't execute the worker immediately after enqueued. Is there an option?

I can use a flag for the first app launch and solve this, but I am looking for an option from WorkManager library itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set an initial delay on your `PeriodicWorkRequest` (for example, by using this method: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkRequest.Builder#setInitialDelay(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) ).

Comment: This won't work as far as from the source code. Initial delay won't be considered for periodicworkrequest

Comment: Where does it say that? It is now available for PeriodicWorkRequest.

Comment: Okay correct. I was looking at the source code of older version. Thanks that'll work.